# Angular JS page not found using http-server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, httpserver

I have a simple angular app with a directory structure that looks like the following:

```
-lpbm
 -shared
  - js
  - css
 -public
   app.js
   index.html
```

I run http-server within the lpbm folder which creates `http://localhost:8080`

I then try to access `http://localhost:8080/public/index.html` but i get a blank page and the following error in my terminal window: `"GET /public/index.html" Error (404): "not found"`

This was working before, and something random must be stopping it from working correctly, as the directory and url structure are correct. I've tried removing all my custom files other than my **index.html** and **app.js** which are below

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cheapest Fares</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/lpbm.css">
    <script src="../shared/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../shared/js/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="../shared/js/angular-message-format.js"></script>
    <script src="../shared/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../shared/js/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-app="app" ng-strict-di ng-controller="AppController as app">
    <h1>Our cheapest fares from London</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <ng-view autoscroll></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages', 'ngMessageFormat', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])


.controller('AppController', function() {
    console.log('working?');
})
```

Is there any obvious reason this is not working? if i open up a test angular app and do the same http-server process it works, suggesting it is something wrong with my app.js or index.html but i can't spot what, i've literally removed everything and it still refuses to load.

Comment: I am not able to see the application context in url "http://localhost:8080/public/index.html"

Comment: @Arpit you should be able too though right? it was working on friday

Comment: Is you browser console printing : working?

Comment: The problem is your server code.  Why do you post html and angular code?  index.html is 404.  That's the problem. 
Try getting rid of the /public and just access index.html.  Perhaps you exposing public as the root directly for http.

Comment: @tpie the reason i posted other code is because the server works fine when i do the same in other folders, i've not changed anything within the server apart from start it. If i change the url to just localhost:8080/index.html it works but it can't find any of the shared files, ie the js and files no longer found in localhost:8080/shared/js/

Comment: If it's finding your index.html when you go to that address, then it's as I said. Just move your shared folder in public and it should fix everything.

Comment: you are right @tpie it fixes it moving the shared folder into public but why do you think it was working previously, then suddenly stopped and forced me to move the directory?

Comment: Post your server code and I'll show you.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved your code to Plunker and removed additional dependecies and all seems to be working fine.

I would sugest to do the same on your side as well. If this is not an issue, try to look on the server side of the app.
Also the error

```
"GET /public/index.html" Error (404): "not found"
```

you've mentioned might be sugesting this.

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/MLkrJdzyd7mPEHyYe1v6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason your files are accessible at `http://localhost:8080/` and not `http://localhost:8080/public/` is because you are using a virtual mount path.  In a framework like express, for example, that is done like this:

`app.use('/', express.static('public'));`

This determines what parts of your server are accessible client-side.  The first argument ('/') sets the location that clients navigate to in order to access the files at the location in the second argument ('public').  The reason your `/shared` folder was not accessible until you place it in the `/public` directory is because it was outside the scope of what was being exposed to the client.

If you aren't using express, the code may look slightly different, but this is essentially what is happening.  Somehow this line of code was uncommented or added to your server.